# How to create an application folder when application installs?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I create a folder for my application? I know that `CreateDirectory` method exist but how can I create it once time when application installing on device? I don't want always to create a folder when application starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It safe to use it on startup and there is no way to create the folders while installing.

From [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory/p/System.String/):

> `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory` Method creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path unless they already exist.

So  if the directory already exists it will not create it.

Comment: What do you mean by startup? Does it means `OnStart` method in PCL?

Comment: I mean when application starts

Comment: I think that another elegant solution should be. Your solution made me check does folder exist every time when application start. I don't need an extra operation.

Comment: whatever you do you will need to check something, e.g. another way is to save in settings if it opened for first time or not.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to create an Application folder when the app is *installing*, you have to do it when your app starts.

You can read more about application directories on our documentation website here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/#Application_Directories